# Time in Case Custom Field Value - conditional on case status

Tags: reporting, workflow, case, custom-field, datetime

The business has a field that captures an operational process (Investigation, Quote, in build, UAT etc) call this 'Ops Stage' and the core status of a case (in progress, waiting for customer etc).

There is a requirement to capture the time a case sits in each 'Ops stage' but not have the timer running when the status of the ticket is sitting with the customer. Essentially reporting that on average the business usually sits in UAT for 30 hours. The tricky part is that it isn't linear and can move around the various 'Ops stages'

I have found similar use cases, however none of what I have found seems to be conditional on the case status and really just captures the date/time something enters a stage and exists a stage. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can write a trigger to capture each stage date time and based on those date time you can calculate the difference between two stages.

Comment: Hi Scott, welcome to StackExchange. How were those other uses cases implemented? Couldn't you just use the combined Stage/Status value instead of only the Stage values?